# Combine datepicker and timepicker to make DateTime object in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to insert DateTime object values in my Sqlite tabel which is

```
"CREATE TABLE Customer (ID INTEGER NOT NULL primary key, Name varchar(50), Designation varchar(50), Age INTEGER, DateModified datetime, DateCreated datetime)"
```

For this I have this function to return formatted string from datetime values

```
private string DateTimeSQLite(DateTime datetime)
{
      string dateTimeFormat = "{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}";
      return string.Format(dateTimeFormat, datetime.Year,        datetime.Month, datetime.Day, datetime.Hour, datetime.Minute, datetime.Second,datetime.Millisecond);
}
```

I have one DatePicker and TimePicker in my app . I have to combine these value to pass to this funcion.How do I combine both controls values ??

Comment: Does SQLite not allow you to use parameterized SQL? You really shouldn't need to format the value...

Comment: I dont think so http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html - search for "parameters".

Comment: Will you please provide any sample I want to insert date and time using these pickers?

Comment: No, I don't have any experience with TimePicker... although I'd expect it to give you a `TimeSpan` which you can add to the `DateTime` from the `DatePicker`. But I'd strongly advise you to use parameterized SQL if you possibly can.

Comment: Any sqlite queries in which date time column present?

Comment: Ah, so you're already not including the values directly into the SQL, it's just because SQLite doesn't support datetime properly? In that case, I see your point - but you'd be better off using `return datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` (Otherwise you wouldn't get the right zero-padding, for example.)

Comment: Have you tried DateTime date = DatePicker.Value.Date + TimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;?